# How to combine many projects into one project

Tags: iphone, xcode, projects

I want to take several iphone projects that I wrote and combine them into one project.  What's the easiest way to do this?  I would like it if I could access all these projects from one button on the iphone home screen.

Answer (score 1):

How complex are the projects? If they are all single-view or navigation based, setting up a new tabbar-based project and assigning each sub-project to a tab is a very efficient way to combine them into one package. There are many other ways to do this, and the "best" way will really depend on the types of projects you are combining.

Comment: Yes, they're navigation based.

How do I add a project as a sub project?  I mean, what xcode commands do I use?

Comment: Basically you can Add Existing Files and add the classes/nibs that you used in your current projects to the new "combined" project. Then tie each tab item to one of the nibs that you added. There's no automatic way to do it.